# Eclipse Jar problems

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

I am working on a java project in eclipse . When i export the jar file , a Jlabel picture and a message box icon is not showing other than this all icons are shown .Where is the problem with those two icons?

Comment: how shall we know without seeing any code / knowing nothing about your project? (And no, I did not downvote your question...)

Comment: @Turing85 there's a big one ..I am posting the code of jlabel        ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon("src/triasha.png"); // load the image to a imageIcon
     Image image = imageIcon.getImage(); // transform it 
     Image newimg = image.getScaledInstance(412, 80,  java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH); // scale it the smooth way  
     imageIcon = new ImageIcon(newimg);  // transform it back
     jLabel1.setIcon(imageIcon);

Comment: No... just no. Please update your question. Nobody is able to read that in a comment as one-liner.

Comment: To update your question use [edit] option below your post.

Comment: Does this work when run from Eclipse and not when running the exported JAR ? Perhaps you just forgot to add that icon to the export so it is missing from the JAR or was not copied text to the JAR ?

Comment: @Marged Thanks ! Solved my problem everything is running well now :)

Comment: @Italian How did you solve your problem ? Is there something others can learn from ? If yes, please answer your own question. If someone helped you solve the problem: ask him to post an answer for you.

Comment: Consider updating your question with more details which would allow us to reproduce your problem. Also if you solved this problem consider posting your solution as answer. If this question will stay as it is it will probably be deleted sooner or later.

Comment: I just added a package images and shipped all the icons to it and used the java.net.url and getresource() function to get the image .Boom that solved it

Answer (score 2):

1. Add a separate Package and transfer all the images to it .
2. And then get the location of the images by using

   ```
   java.net.URL url = classname.class.getResource("/package/iconname.png");
   ```
3. Load the image like this

   ```
   ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon(url);
   ```
4. And then set the image like this

   ```
   jLabel1.setIcon(imageIcon);
   ```

and voila! done :)